# How to prevent Google map from moving when panning?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to implement dram move event with Google Maps on Android.
Inside onTouchEvent I want to freeze the map when MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN is fired so user can start dragging the handle from the center saved at MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and use MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE to capture the moving points. Finally when MotionEvent.ACTION_UP is fired, save the new location and allow map to be movable again.

I am plying with different options, but haven't found a way yet. Any hit will be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting center at MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE for the overlay currently being dragged.

```
mapController.setCenter(selectedPoint.getPoint());//drag the handle here
```